# Compare two arrays of hashes and return new object

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have two arrays of hashes.

```
burgers = [
            {:id => 1, :name => "cheese burger"},
            {:id => 2, :name => "royale"},
            {:id => 3, :name => "big mac"},
            {:id => 4, :name => "angus beef"}
          ]

eaten =   [
            {:burger_id => 1},
            {:burger_id => 2}
          ]
```

I would like to return an array or uneaten burgers, where `burgers[:id]` does not equal `eaten[:burger_id]`. In `burgers_not_eaten_method`, I have the expected return value.

```
def burgers_not_eaten
  #Not sure how to compare burger[:id] with eaten[:burger_id]
  burgers.reject { |burger| burger[:id] == #eaten burger_id }
  # Expected:  [{:id => 3, :name => "big mac"},{:id => 4, :name => "angus beef"}]
end
```

Comment: Just a fun note: if the ids are not strictly necessary, I recommend using  a `Set`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close, to make it easy I'd snag all the "eaten" ids into an array, and check for inclusion in that array, like so:

```
BURGERS = [
            {:id => 1, :name => "cheese burger"},
            {:id => 2, :name => "royale"},
            {:id => 3, :name => "big mac"},
            {:id => 4, :name => "angus beef"}
          ]

EATEN = [
          {:burger_id => 1},
          {:burger_id => 2}
        ]

def burgers_not_eaten
  eaten_ids = EATEN.map { |e| e[:burger_id] }
  BURGERS.reject { |burger| eaten_ids.include?(burger[:id]) }
end

burgers_not_eaten
# => [{:id=>3, :name=>"big mac"}, {:id=>4, :name=>"angus beef"}]
```

Comment: Ahah 41 seconds ahead and the only difference between your answer and mine is the usage of `reject`/`select`! You got the credits ;)

Comment: Alterntively, `eaten_ids = EATEN.flat_map { |burger| burger.values }`, so that you needn't change that line if key names in `EATEN`'s hashes are changed.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.